# How do I get the html from a contentEditable div to go inside of a hidden text form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, rte

I don't believe that you can use the input straight from a content editable div and submit it in a form, so I figured that I could just have a hidden text field and do something like this:

```
var blog_post = $("#editable_div").html();
$('#hidden_text_area').val(blog_post);
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? It is not working with what I have. I thought that maybe the `$('#hidden_text_area').val(blog_post);` needed to be triggered by an event, but I tried it with a click and it didn't work.

```
$('#clicker').click(function(){
  $('#hidden_text_area').val(blog_post);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#clicker').click(function(){
 var blog_post = $("#editable_div").html();
 $('#hidden_text_area').val(blog_post);
})
```

Because it does not look like your blog_post variable contains the html content when you click this button.

Comment: Ok I see. The blog post variable was being set only on load, which made it blank. I was imagining that it was listening as I typed.

Answer (score 0):

please check alert($('#hidden_text_area')) is giving object or not . if it is not giving object then it has problem otherwise  $('#hidden_text_area').val(blog_post); should work.

Comment: it is returning [object Object]

Comment: I am not getting an error. The hidden_text_area is just not being populated with the html. For now I am not hiding the text area, so I can see that it just stays blank.

Comment: please see alert(blog_post) is this giving any value ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work well for me, however, please be aware that the html in the value attribute will be escaped:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="content">
    <p style="background-color: blue;">Testing</p>
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="hit me" id="btn" />
<div id="parent">
    <input type="text" name="testinput" id="inputtest" value="" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var html_contents = $("#content").html();
    $("#inputtest").val(html_contents);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't including the html_contents variable in the click event. I thought it was updating on it's own.